# Is there the equivelent of a Canvas control in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to be able to do some direct drawing in Xamarin Forms. Is there a control equivelent to a canvas? I saw somewhere that maybe the AbsoluteLayout was, but I need something that I can, for example, execute a `DrawString` or `DrawArc` on. Does such a thing exist, or do you have to create a custom control?

Comment: I have added an answer, I hope it can be of help. The documentation for Skia is great, and the library is very easy to use. Please remember to mark my answer as accepted if you think it answers your question appropriately!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I was hoping for a solution that was native to Xamarin, though.

Comment: This NuGet is pretty standard, but yeah, it doesn't come with Forms by default. That shouldn't be a problem, though.

Comment: Yes, by searching, SkiaSharp is the best way, there are some article about using SkiaSharp, you can take a look:[Drawing with SkiaSharp](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/drawing-with-skiasharp/) and [Getting Started With SkiaSharp With Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-skiasharp-with-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with [SkiaSharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/), it basically allows you to do more or less the same than you can do in the native canvas of Android.

To use it:

1. Add the NuGet package `SkiaSharp.Views.Forms` to your projects.
2. Add the Skia namespace to your page or layout:

```xml
xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;assembly=SkiaSharp.Views.Forms"
```

3. Add the Skia canvas view, defining the name of the callback method that will be used to draw on it from the code behind:

```xml
<skia:SKCanvasView                
    x:Name="CanvasView"
    PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface"/>
```

4. Draw whatever you want:

```cs
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
{
    var info = args.Info;
    var surface = args.Surface;
    var canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();

    // In this example, we will draw a circle in the middle of the canvas
    var paint = new SKPaint
    {
        Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill,
        Color = Color.Red.ToSKColor(), // Alternatively: SKColors.Red
    };
    canvas.DrawCircle(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint);
}
```